# How to transform reactive chain to either true or false depending if empty

Tags: java, project-reactor

```
Mono<SingleChoice> filter = Mono.just(this)
.filter(predicate)
.//return true if data still exists else false
;
```

I would like to write a logic where i validate mono by filter operator.
So if filter pass then mono contains data but if filter failed then there is an empty mono, but i don't need the object on which filter was performed instead i need boolean result. how could i achieve this is reactive programing.

Comment: Using map instead of filter would give you a Mono<Boolean>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hasElement` operator does exactly what you describe. You can use it like this:

```java
Mono<Boolean> booleanMono = Mono.just(11)
    .filter(i -> i > 10)
    .hasElement();
```

Comment: This does exactly what i was looking for. best and short answer